# count distinct of text field in data studio increased when using filter

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I want to count the number of sessions with a certain event label in google data studio. I have created a new field in data studio on a google analytics source like this:

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE WHEN Event Label = "Form Start" THEN Session ID ELSE "" END)
```

where Session ID is a custom dimension from GA (string). 
The problem is that when I for example pull this new metric to a scorecard, I get a value of 6, if I then add a filter on this scorecard with Event Label = "Form Start" (the exact same event label as in the case statement of the new field) the metric is increased to 23! (which is the correct number).

Is there some data truncation going on in data studio behind the scenes or why does using the filter increase the distinct count?

Answer (score 0):

The weird numbers you're seeing could be due to sampling. At the bottom of the report in "view" mode, it should indicate if the numbers are sampled or not.

Also, the Unique Events metric should tell you the number of times a specific event happened per session. You might not need to do all that custom work in data studio, just a filter for the label.

Comment: Ok, I can't see any information about sampling in the report but it would explain the problem. Is there a way to remove sampling? I'm trying to create custom conversion rates, that's why I need the calculated metric (following this: https://datarunsdeep.com.au/blog/creating-custom-conversion-rates-and-funnels-google-data-studio)

Comment: You can use a shorter date range. Otherwise, you’ll need to pay for GA360

Comment: in that case you shouldn't have any sampling issues, unless you're pulling hundreds of million worth of sessions.

Comment: The sesssions are around 500 000 and there is no problem counting the unique number of session ids. The problem seems to arise when mixing in the event labels (which are on hit level) which increases the detail level the calculation has to go through. I just find it strange that there is no problem filtering on event label  but only to use it in a case statement.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the metric in a table along with the other dimensions to make sure it makes sense?

Comment: It makes sense when calculating it for around one day of data, the issue arises when increasing the date range

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something that requires the `COUNT_DISTINCT` function, but would a simpler, different formula work?

```
CASE
  WHEN Event Label = "Form Start" THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

This would create a number field that that can be used in the metric element of a Scorecard with multiple aggregation options?  The key option being SUM :)

Comment: Yes, I wish that would work, tried it already but the sum of that statement actually always returns 1 :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I think, where I was trying to tally all the pages with a certain category in the meta:

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(idio:industry, '.*Agriculture.*') THEN "Agriculture"
else "Others"
END
```

In your case, I think you would use this:

```
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Event Label, '.*Form Start.*') THEN Session ID
else "Others"
END
```